# Sending data multiple times over a single socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, c#-4.0

Server side code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            static Socket sck;
            Console.WriteLine("Server Started...");
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sck.Bind(new IPEndPoint(0, 1234));
            while (true)
            {
                sck.Listen(100);
                Socket accepted = sck.Accept();
                buffer = new byte[accepted.SendBufferSize];
                int bytesRead = accepted.Receive(buffer);
                byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
                    formatted[i] = buffer[i];
                string strdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
                Console.WriteLine(strdata + "\r");
            //    sck.Close();
            }
```

Client side code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            static Socket sck;
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint localEndpt = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
            try
            {
                sck.Connect(localEndpt);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Write("Unable to Connect");
            }
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Text");
                string sendtext = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] Data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendtext);
                sck.Send(Data);
                Console.WriteLine("Data Sent!");
                //sck.Close();
                //Console.Read();
            }
```

I want to send text from the Client side multiple times, however the text is sent only the first time. Please tell me where am i going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your server. You are in a loop listening for a new connection, accepting it and receiving data. Yet what happens is the listening statement see's a client who wants to connect. Your accept statement actually connects the client and your receive statement receieves the first data. After that your server starts listening for a new connection again but is not receiving more data from the already existing connection. You should build a loop around the Accept statement and a loop around the Receive statement on your server to fix this problem

Comment: I moved the listen statement before the loop but i still face the same issue

Comment: As i said, you need to move your receive statement in a loop. You should accept a client once yet receive multiple times